# How can I scale an image using tcpdf?

Tags: php, image, tcpdf

I've got an image of size 490 x 630 that was drawn in corel. It's supposed to have
41.3 mm (wide) and 52.3 mm .

The unit I'm using in my TCPDF class is "mm".

I'm having trouble trying to acomplish this.

What value should I put on setImageScale() ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using an image of format ".png". With ".png" format I had trouble trying to display the image correctly on the pdf. I opened the image in paint and save it as ".jpg" and use it instead. Once I've changed the format I could display the image correctly without any complication. I think there's a bug on PCDF related to ".png" images.

Answer (score 0):

What worked form me is `$pdf->setImageScale(1.66)`.

This was to get the font size translation from `px` to `points` as close as possible, plus, calculating the cell positions (my program specifies the cell position with an `X` and `Y` coordinate also in pixels.

In other words, my entire document is in pixels and I render it in points (pt) and I got a very near *WYSIWYG*.

*Tested on IE, FireFox and Opera.*